# Create Archive Page for Post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm developing custom theme for my website.

The homepage `example.com` is the company profile page

I want to move archive blog posts to `example.com/blog`

I try to edit the permalink to append `/blog` but it works only for single post

what currently am already doing is

- create a custom template for page and set the URL to `/blog`

```
<?php
/**
 * page-blog.php
 * Template Name: Blog Home
 * Template Post Type: page
 */

get_header();
?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'components/grid', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php
get_footer();
```

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

go to setting->permalinks in permalinks setting  in optional setting you will find categories base in categories base you have to enter your base for archives

[image]